# Как нарисовать дугу на svg для сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, svg

Как можно нарисовать такую дугу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900

Comment: Тег `path` атрибут `d` параметр `a`. [Инструкция на MDN.](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Решение с использованием `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`**

Идея заключается в том, чтобы показывать только часть окружности, а остальную часть скрывать пробелом  `stroke-dasharray ="314 314"`
Первая цифра это - длина штриха, вторая цифра - длина пробела. 
 Эти цифры выбраны не случайно, - так как  длина окружности при радиусе `100px` равна:
`c = 2*P*R = 628px`

Для окружности SVG считает началом пути положительную ось `X`-ов.  Но нам надо рисовать от оси `Y`-ов.    Поэтому поворачиваем нашу окружность против часовой стрелки на 90 градусов
 `<g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)">`

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="400" height="400">
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1F2024" />
 <g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)">   
   <circle id="fon" cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="#673E93" stroke-width="5"   stroke-dasharray ="314 " stroke-dashoffset="314" fill="none" />
    
   </g> 
   
   <line x1="150" y1="240" x2="150" y2="290" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" />

 </svg>
```

Далее делаем расчет длины для зеленой (R=115px) и синей окружностей (R=130px)
Для зеленой длина окружности равна = `722px`
Для синей окружности  равна = `816px`

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="400" height="400">
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1F2024" />
 <g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)" fill="none" stroke-width="5">   
    <circle id="fon" cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="#673E93"  stroke-dasharray ="314 " stroke-dashoffset="314" />
    <circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="115"  stroke="#05957A"    stroke-dasharray ="365 " stroke-dashoffset="360"  /> 
    <circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="130"  stroke="#0F72AF"    stroke-dasharray ="408.2 428" stroke-dashoffset="488" />
    </g> 
   
   <line x1="150" y1="240" x2="150" y2="290" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" />
 </svg>
```

Далее необходимо добавить три четверти окружностей с радиусами:
`100px`, `115px` `130px`
**Идея та же - используем атрибут `stroke-dasharray ="157 471"`** , где
`157` - длина штриха, равная одной четверти длины окружности при радиусе равном - 100px
`471` - длина пробела равная 3/4 длины окружности

для двух других окружностей с большими радиусами цифры будут другие. Полная длина окружности вычисляется  по формуле - **C = 2*P*R**

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="400" height="400">
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1F2024" />
 
   <g fill="none"  stroke-width="10" stroke="#2A2D2F">
        <circle id="gray100" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"       stroke-dasharray ="157 471 "      />
          <circle id="gray115" cx="150" cy="150" r="115"     stroke-dasharray ="180.5  541 " /> 
       <circle id="gray130" cx="150" cy="150" r="130"   stroke-dasharray ="204.1  612 " />
    </g>   
 <g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)" fill="none" stroke-width="6">   
    <circle id="fon" cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="#673E93"  stroke-dasharray ="314 " stroke-dashoffset="314" />
    <circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="115"  stroke="#05957A"    stroke-dasharray ="365 " stroke-dashoffset="360"  /> 
    <circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="130"  stroke="#0F72AF"    stroke-dasharray ="408.2 428" stroke-dashoffset="488" />
   </g>
 
   
   <line x1="150" y1="240" x2="150" y2="290" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" /> 
    <text font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" x="155" y="140" stroke="#999B98" fill="#999B98"> Теплоэнергия % </text>
 </svg>
```

### Анимация SVG изображения

Для анимации совместно используются атрибуты `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`

На каждый атрибут применена отдельная анимация изменения параметров от нуля до максимального значения -  `values="0;314"`

**Запуск анимации происходит по клику на svg изображении** - `begin="svg1.click"`
Анимации цветных кругов идут последовательно друг за другом
Например: условием запуска зелёного круга является окончание  анимации пурпурного круга, плюс пауза `0.25s`

```
 begin="purle1.end+0.25s"
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="400" height="400">
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1F2024" />
 
   <g fill="none"  stroke-width="10" stroke="#2A2D2F">
        <circle id="gray100" cx="150" cy="150" r="100"       stroke-dasharray ="157 471 "      />
          <circle id="gray115" cx="150" cy="150" r="115"     stroke-dasharray ="180.5  541 " /> 
       <circle id="gray130" cx="150" cy="150" r="130"   stroke-dasharray ="204.1  612 " />
    </g>   
 <g transform="rotate(-90 150 150)" fill="none" stroke-width="6">   
    
    <circle id="fon" cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="#673E93"  stroke-dasharray ="314 " stroke-dashoffset="314" >
    <animate id="purle" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" values="0;314" dur="5s"   repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>          
     <animate id="purle1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" values="0;314" dur="5s" repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>          
   
   </circle>
 

 <circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="115"  stroke="#05957A"    stroke-dasharray ="365 " stroke-dashoffset="360"  > 
      <animate id="green" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="purle1.end+0.25s" values="0;365" dur="5s"   repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>          
     <animate id="green1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="purle1.end+0.25s" values="0;365" dur="5s" repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>       
     
    </circle>

   <circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="130"  stroke="#0F72AF"    stroke-dasharray ="408.2 428" stroke-dashoffset="488" >
                <animate id="blue" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="green1.end+0.25s" values="408;0;408" dur="5s"   repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>          
     <animate id="blue1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="green1.end+0.25s" values="488;0;488" dur="8s" repeatCount="1"          fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive"/>       

     </circle>
 </g>
   
   
   <line x1="150" y1="240" x2="150" y2="290" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" /> 
    <line x1="152" y1="16" x2="152" y2="60" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" /> 
    <text font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" x="155" y="140" stroke="#999B98" fill="#999B98"> Теплоэнергия % </text>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 8):

**Как это делаю я:**

1. Рисуем в любом векторном редакторе (Adobe Illustrator у меня):

[image: Illustrator]

2. Сохраняем в SVG:

[image: SVG]

3. Открываем с любым текстовым редактором:

[image: Text]

4. Копируем код в нашу HTML верстку:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200px" height="200px">
    <path d="M100,194.3c-52.1,0-94.3-42.2-94.3-94.3S47.9,5.7,100,5.7V0C44.8,0,0,44.8,0,100c0,55.2,44.8,100,100,100V194.3z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Из бесплатных вариантов -- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), он фактически на формате SVG построен и им же ограничен.

Comment: @D-side а можно и без векторного редактора, всего несколько строк :-) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661183/28748

Comment: @Alexandr_T а в Inkscape пара перетяжек мышью и одно сочетание клавиш сразу открывает получившийся XML (он у Inkscape под капотом, работа идёт напрямую с SVG). И если вам интересно, он делает дугу [path-командой `A` (Arc, дуга)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs).

Answer (score 8):

```js
(function() {

  // Значения индикаторов от 0 до 100.
  var data = [ 75.00, 64.00, 66.66 ];
  
  var diagramWidth = 320
    , diagramHeight = 320
    , cx = diagramWidth / 2
    , cy = diagramHeight / 2
    , indicatorRadiuses = [ 120, 100, 80 ]
    , maxAngle = 270
    , diagramBgColor = '#1f2024'
    , indicatorBgColor = '#222629'
    , indicatorColors = [ '#0f6eb3', '#00997b', '#6c3b9c' ]
    , indicatorBgWidth = 10
    , indicatorWidth = 6;
  
  function polarToCartesian(cx, cy, radius, deg) {
    var rad = (deg - 90) * Math.PI / 180;
    return {
      x: cx + (radius * Math.cos(rad)),
      y: cy + (radius * Math.sin(rad))
    };
  }

  function indicator(x, y, radius, angleStart, angleEnd) {
    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, -angleEnd)
      , end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, angleStart)
      , largeArc = angleEnd - angleStart <= 180 ? 0 : 1;
    return [
      'M', start.x, start.y, 
      'A', radius, radius, 0, largeArc, 1, end.x, end.y
    ].join(' ');       
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    scene.setAttribute('width', diagramWidth);
    scene.setAttribute('height', diagramHeight);
    scene.style.backgroundColor = diagramBgColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
      path.setAttribute('fill-opacity', 0);
      path.setAttribute('stroke', indicatorBgColor);
      path.setAttribute('stroke-width', indicatorBgWidth);
      path.setAttribute('d', indicator(cx, cy, indicatorRadiuses[i], 0, maxAngle));
      scene.appendChild(path);
  
      path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
      path.setAttribute('fill-opacity', 0);
      path.setAttribute('stroke', indicatorColors[i]);
      path.setAttribute('stroke-width', indicatorWidth);
      path.setAttribute('d', indicator(cx, cy, indicatorRadiuses[i], 0, data[i] / 100 * maxAngle));
      scene.appendChild(path);
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<svg id="scene"></svg>
```