# Линия с круговым отступом

Tags: css, html5, css3, анимация, svg

Помогите разобраться, как сделано сердце с отступом вокруг него. Как получить такую же изогнутую линию? Это возможно с помощью CSS, HTML?

Я знаю, как добавить сердце с помощью CSS или картинки, но как добиться изогнутой границы вокруг него?

Похоже, `border-radius` здесь не поможет...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевод вопроса: [Line with indented circle  @hermann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506134/)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30506134/7394871

Comment: два сердца сделать да и все.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно же, `border-radius` поможет. Но придётся подбирать размеры вложенных блоков и согласовывать толщину границ с толщиной линий в иконках.

### CSS

1. Круг помещаем псевдоэлементом в блок с `overflow:hidden;`. Получаем дугу.
2. Сердечко берём [из Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/heart-o/). Чтобы задать иконку через стили, создаём ещё один блок с псевдоэлементом. Если бы сердечко не выступало за нижнюю границу дуги и ему не грозил бы добавленный нами `overflow:hidden;`, то мы поместили бы оба пседоэлемента в один блок.
3. Позиционируем собранный блок поверх картинки с нижней рыжей границей. Даём отрицательный `bottom`, чтобы опуститься на ширину границы.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/MoyXxp

```css
.arch {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
.arch:before {
  background: white;
  border: solid 3px orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 133.333333%;
}

.heart {
  position: absolute; bottom: -3px; right: 60px;
  width: 48px; height: 36px;
}
.heart:after {
  color: orange;
  content: '\f08a'; /* http://fontawesome.io/icon/heart-o/ */
  display: block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute; bottom: -4px; left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo {
  background: #9cf;
  border-bottom: solid 3px orange;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo"><div class="heart"><div class="arch"></div></div></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T Спасибо за перевод интересных вопросов и ответов!

Answer (score 3):

Вот идея о том, как вы можете реализовать этот макет с помощью `inline` svg.

### SVG :

- Первый `path` - это круговая линия с отступом. Вырезанная окружность
  создается с помощью команды дуги (`arc`)
- Второй элемент `path` - это само сердце. Патч использует команду
  кривой Безье для верхней части сердца.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/200" alt="">
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 18.4">
    <path stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.8" fill="#fff" d="M-1 21 V18 H79.5 A7 7 0 1 1 90.5 18 H101 V21" />
    <path stroke="orange" stroke-width="0.8" fill="#fff" d="M85 18 L81 13 C80 10 85 10 85 12 C85 10 90 10 89 13z " />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Дополнительные сведения о командах path в SVG см. [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) и [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=897).

---

*Перевод ответа [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30507281/6263942).*

Answer (score 2):

### SVG + Анимация

Три последовательных анимации:

1. Рисование изогнутой линии вокруг сердца
2. Рисование контура сердца
3. Заполнение цветом

Первые две анимации реализованы с помощью изменения атрибута патча `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения до нуля, тем самым реализован эффект рисования линии.

Для точного вычисления длины пути линии и контура сердца применяем команду JS `getTotalLength()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
   
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="100%" height="100%" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
        d="M-1 21 V18 H79.5 A7 7 0 1 1 90.5 18 H101 V21" /> 
</svg> 
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
</html>
```

Для изогнутой линии длина получилась равной `128px` Для контура сердца =`26px`

Подставляем эти значения в анимацию атрибута stroke-dashoffset.

**Начало анимации - click по треугольнику в правом нижнем углу**

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/200" alt="">
<div>
   <svg id="svg1" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 100 18.4">

  <path stroke="orange" stroke-width="1" fill="#fff"  stroke-dasharray="128" stroke-dashoffset="128"
 d="M-1 21 V18 H79.5 A7 7 0 1 1 90.5 18 H101 V21" >
 <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="128;0" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</path>

   <path stroke="crimson" stroke-width="1" fill="#fff" stroke-dasharray="26" stroke-dashoffset="26"
  d="M85 18 L81 13 C80 10 85 10 85 12 C85 10 90 10 89 13z" >
  <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="26;0" begin="an1.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  restart="whenNotActive"/> 
     <animate attributeName="fill" values="white; crimson" begin="an2.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  restart="whenNotActive"/> 
</path> 
 <path stroke="orange" stroke-width="1" fill="orange" d="M83.5 17 L83.5 9 L89 13.5z " >
<animate id="btn1" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" dur="3s"  begin="svg1.click" />
<set attributeName="visibility" to="hidden" begin="btn1.end"/>
  </path> 
</svg>
</div>
```

**Похожие темы:**

- [Анимировать по очереди SVG Path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/630262/28748)
- [Как нарисовать дугу на svg для сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660741/28748)
- [Cоздать круглую стрелку с использованием только HTML и CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647150/28748)
- [Линия до и после текста над картинкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/648348/28748)
- [Тайна вырезания контура в фигуре SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/665187/28748)